# Glossaries from memoir manual in overleaf and arara

Tags: memoir, overleaf, arara

I am reading the [memoir manual](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) and I am having problems with section 17.3 about glossaries. I have this MWE that I call it `example.tex`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeindex
\makeglossary[acro]

\begin{document}
A term for the index: limit\index{Limit}. Now an entry for the glossary \glossary[acro]{HTML}{HyperText Markup Language}.

\clearpage
\printindex

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Acronyms}
\printglossary[acro]
\end{document}
```

If I compile it in my machine as says in the manual, for example with the following chain

```
lualatex example.tex
makeindex example.idx
makeindex -s basic.gst -o acro.gls acro.glo
lualatex example.tex
```

everything goes well, where `basic.gst` is as says in the memoir manual:

```
%%% basic.gst basic makindex glossary style file
 %%% Output style parameters
 preamble "\\begin{theglossary}"
 postamble "\n\\end{theglossary}\n"
 item_0    "\n\\glossitem"
 delim_0   "{\\memglonum{"
 encap_suffix "}}}"
 headings_flag 1
 heading_prefix "\\doglobookmark{"
 heading_suffix "}"
 %%% Input style parameters
 keyword "\\glossaryentry"
```

But I have two questions: (1) If I want to compile it in overleaf, the index is built correctly but the glossary cannot be compiled and nothing is built. So there is a way to achieve memoir glossaries working in overleaf? And (2) I am not sure how to compile it using `arara`. According to the manual, `options` takes a list of raw command line options and appends it to the actual system call, so I tried:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: makeindex: { options: [ '-s basic.gst', '-o acro.gls acro.glo' ] }
% arara: lualatex
```

But I am always getting a failure saying:

```
Index style file -o acro.gls acro.glo not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
```

So the second question is, how to pass this options to `arara`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Overleaf uses latexmk to process your files. We add a number of rules for common auxiliary processing steps. You can see details of these at [How does Overleaf compile my project?](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F).

Our default rules for glossaries and indices are not set up to work with `memoir`'s methods for preparing the acronym list with `makeindex`. You can modify the `glo2gls` subroutine to work with `memoir`'s setup:

```
##############
# Glossaries #
##############
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'glo2gls' );
add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'glo2gls');  # from Overleaf v1
sub glo2gls {
    system("makeindex -s basic.gst -o acro.gls acro.glo");
}
```

With your example code, you'd also need to load the `hyperref` package and provide a definition of `\doglobookmark` to avoid error messages caused by the contents of the `.gst` file.

If you use anything else that would have been processed by the original definition of `glo2gls`, you may need to split this into two subroutines rather than redefining the existing one.

### Complete example

**example.tex**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeindex
\makeglossary[acro]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\doglobookmark[1]{%
    \def\@tempa{Symbols}\def\@tempb{#1}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb %
    \phantomsection\pdfbookmark[0]{Analphabetics}{Analphabetics-glo}%
    \else%
    \phantomsection\pdfbookmark[0]{#1}{#1-glo}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A term for the index: limit\index{Limit}. Now an entry for the glossary \glossary[acro]{HTML}{HyperText Markup Language}.

\clearpage
\printindex

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Acronyms}
\printglossary[acro]
\end{document}
```

**basic.gst**

```
%%% basic.gst basic makindex glossary style file
 %%% Output style parameters
 preamble "\\begin{theglossary}"
 postamble "\n\\end{theglossary}\n"
 item_0    "\n\\glossitem"
 delim_0   "{\\memglonum{"
 encap_suffix "}}}"
 headings_flag 1
 heading_prefix "\\doglobookmark{"
 heading_suffix "}"
 %%% Input style parameters
 keyword "\\glossaryentry"
```

Example Overleaf project: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tjcjgwkvpbbm